# Convert single row to single column in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to have this statement return as a column instead of a row? Possibly using a pivot query?

```
select * from MYTABLE Where SOMECOLUMN = RESULT THAT RETURNS ONE RECORD
```

Comment: You mean with each column from that single row, as its own row with a single column? Which is, as you already seem to know, a pivot operation (or unpivot). So what have you tried? Which version of Oracle? What data types are the columns?

Comment: I just discovered the pivot operation today and I want to be able to convert one row to one column without having to supply all the column names, I have 140 columns in the table. From there I am going to try and add another column with user_tab_columns.column_name so I can have a columns name and its value side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple function that makes what you want, it returns a table so you can invoke it as : Select * from TABLE(mypkg.RowToCol) , as example it will return a row of the EMP table wich EName is "KING".

```
create or replace PACKAGE mypkg AS
  TYPE ColTypRec IS RECORD (field_value varchar2(100),field_name Varchar2(100));
  TYPE ColTyp IS TABLE of ColTypRec;
end;

FUNCTION RowToCol RETURN ColTyp PIPELINED AS
c sys_refcursor;
col_tochar_names varchar(500);
col_names        varchar(500);
data             ColTypRec;
begin
--usage select * from TABLE(mypkg.RowToCol)
SELECT RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, 'TO_CHAR('||column_name||') as '||column_name || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'),   ',') , 
       RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, column_name || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'),   ',') 
       INTO  col_tochar_names, col_names
FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE table_name='EMP';
--dbms_output.put_line(col_tochar_names);
--dbms_output.put_line(col_names);
Open c for  'SELECT fieldvalue,fieldname from ( ' ||
            ' SELECT '||col_tochar_names ||
            ' FROM emp where emp.ename=''KING'' '||
            ' ) '||
            ' UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (fieldvalue FOR fieldname IN ('||col_names||')) '||
            'order by fieldname';
LOOP
  FETCH c INTO data;
  EXIT  WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
  PIPE  ROW(data);  
END LOOP;
CLOSE c;
end;
end; --Body Package
```

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose you can create a dynamic SQl variabile string and execute it inside a stored procedure, that variabile should concatenate all the fields names you need in a pivot query, like the one i show you below this text.

As example we can have the emp table , as you can see we extract only one row from the table where emp.name='KING', then we transpose it using the UNPIVOT statement. The name of the columns we transpose are ENAME, JOBand EMPNO but we could transpose other columns. You have to convert the columns to the same data type, since they must fit a single column, i used TO_CHAR(empno) in the example. I returned the field name too in the main select but you can omit it. Hope it helps.

```
select  fieldvalue,fieldname from (
    SELECT ename,job,to_char(empno) as empno
    FROM emp where emp.ename='KING'
    )
    UNPIVOT (fieldvalue FOR fieldname IN (ename as 'ENAME', job as 'JOB', empno as 'EMPNO'))
    order by fieldname ;
```

Comment: It looks like this won't work for me since all the columns are not of the same type.  Thanks anyways :-/

Comment: Hey i changed my answer to show you how you can convert your columns to a single data type. I used TO_CHAR for converting empno that is an integer to a string.